# Elementary proof of $e > (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\frac{1}{k}} $ for $k>2~$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I saw proofs of $e < (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+0.5}$, but how to prove the inequality:

$
e > (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\frac{1}{k}}
$

for $k>2$ and sufficiently large $n$? I'm interested in elementary solutions (without using derivatives or Taylor expansion), suitable for early stages of a calculus course.

Comment: Do you mean $>$ or $<$?

Comment: I bet there is no solution without using derivatives (or Taylor expansion)

Comment: BTW, I've tried to follow the solutions of  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259175/is-left1-frac1n-rightn1-2-decreasing) question. I think it should be enough to prove that (1+1/n)^(n+1/k) is increasing, but I'm not able to work this out.

Answer (score 3):

Cauchy-Schwarz says
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)
&=\int_n^{n+1}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\
&\le\left(\int_n^{n+1}\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_n^{n+1}1\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
That is,
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}\le e\tag2
$$
For any $\epsilon\gt0$, if $n\ge\frac1{8\epsilon}+\frac\epsilon2-\frac12$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\left(n+\frac12-\epsilon\right)^2
&=n(n+1)+\overbrace{\frac14+\epsilon^2-2\left(n+\frac12\right)\epsilon}^{\le0}\tag{3a}\\
&\le n(n+1)\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, putting together $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get that for $n\ge\frac1{8\epsilon}+\frac\epsilon2-\frac12$
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+\frac12-\epsilon}\le e\tag4
$$

Comment: With [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3259175) cited in the comments, we have $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}\le e\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+\frac12}$$